# Method="POST" stopping database entry

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, post, get

In my JSP application I want to upload a file to a directory and insert some text plus the file extension to the database, both of these work independently very well i.e. I can either insert the text to the database or I can put the file into a directory but when I want to do both method="post" will send the file to the directory but not insert the data, if I use method="get" the opposite happens.

**(EDIT)**

Do the POST and GET methods not allow 2 things to happen at once?

```
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ReplyValidator.jsp" method="post">
            <td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b></td>
            <td><input name="file" type="file"></td>
            Post your reply:<br/>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="topicpost" required="required"></textarea></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Reply"/>
        </form>
```

Thats the form for inputting the data and uploading a file

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>        
<%
      String saveFile = "";
      String contentType = request.getContentType();
      if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
            byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
            int byteRead = 0;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
                  byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
                  totalBytesRead += byteRead;
            }
            String file = new String(dataBytes);
            saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
            saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
            saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));
            int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
            String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length());
            int pos;
            pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
            int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
            int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
            saveFile = "C:/temp/" + saveFile;
            File ff = new File(saveFile);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
            fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
%>
<% } %> 



<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty param.topicpost}">
        <%-- empty so go back to form --%>
        <jsp:forward page="ViewPosts.jsp" />
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>

<c:set var="filename" value="<%=saveFile %>"/>

        <%java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); %>   
            <sql:update>
                INSERT INTO topic_posts (topic_name, post_message, posted_by, post_date, file_upload) values (?,?,?,?,?)
                <sql:param value="${topicname}"/>
                <sql:param value="${param.topicpost}"/>
                <sql:param value="${user}"/>
                <sql:param value="<%=df.format(new java.util.Date())%>"/>
                <sql:param value="${filename}"/>
            </sql:update>    

            <jsp:forward page="index.jsp"></jsp:forward>   
    </c:otherwise>    
</c:choose>
```

Comment: show some code you are tried..

Comment: You aren't showing the code that deals with handling the POSTdata.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't interleave forms and tables. Error recover in browsers can break forms when you try to use to that. [Use a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: @Quentin I've been changing this code thats all originally had a table there, that wasn't in a form originally not something i make a habit of. Although thats nothing to do with the issue but cheers for pointing it out